# Number of ways to arrange 7 boys and 4 girls around a circular table such that no two girls are together

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Find the number of ways to arrange 7 boys and 4 girls such that no two girls are together.

My approach:

- First fix 7 boys. This can be done in $(7-1)!=6!$ ways.
  This creates 7 slots for girls.
- Now these 4 girls can be arranged in $~_7P_4 = {7\choose 3}\cdot 4!=\frac{7!}{3!}$.

So total number of ways to arrange boys and girls according to given condition is $$\frac {6!\cdot 7!}{3!}$$

Is it correct? If not...please tell me how to do it.

P.S. i'm new here. I know the moderation here is pretty strict and people won't like my not using Mathjax to typeset my question.i'm sorry. I will learn it as soon as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange.  Yes, we have gotten a bit of a reputation for being sticklers about moderation, but you have made what is likely to be considered by many a *good post* here, so don't worry too much.  You showed what you tried and show you are willing to put in the effort needed and aren't just looking for someone to do your homework for you.  That's huge, and a great attitude to have.  Learning MathJax and $\LaTeX$ in general will help you as you continue forward, but your post is readable without it right now so it isn't so bad.  I look forward to seeing you make more contributions

Comment: @JMoravitz well said!

Comment: @MathLover Where is my mistake?

Comment: @JMoravitz i tried using mathjax..but i seem to have sabotaged my post further. Could you please help me fix this? Please!

Comment: Thank you @tortue

Comment: Firstly, how many seats does the table have ?

Comment: @true blue anil, it has 11 seats.

Comment: @MathLover **Bingo!** Thanks, that was embarassing.  Answer deleted.

Comment: @HVxvejjw A little question, how did you get a 100 reputation association bonus without being registered on any other stackexchange sites? As per your profile, you have only registered for MSE...

Comment: @Eisenstein , i don't know.

Comment: @HVxvejjw Do you have any other SE accounts?

Comment: I did have an account on other sites. I've been here before...

Comment: @HVxvejjw Oh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your working and explanation are both correct.

As an aside, to further explain why when using circular permutations for the boys we only use $6!$ rather than $7!$, due to the circular nature of the table we don't try to keep track of which way was north or south, etc...  To avoid overcounting we can take a specific boy, for example the youngest one, and allow him to sit anywhere at the table first before anyone else.  From that point on, we can organize our thoughts about where everyone else sits *in reference to him*.  After having seated the youngest boy, there remain only $6$ other boys to arrange around the table after him, hence the result.

Comment: Thank you :-)))